# Is it possible to parameterize selection of source data set of Lookup of Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have Lookup and source data set called "Azure_SQL_1".
Is it possible to parameterize selection of source data set based on variable value?
Variable could have value like "Azure_SQL_1"or "Azure_SQL_2", which would be name of existing data set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parameterize the dataset and linked service as below

[image]

[image]

[image]

### You can also use Variable like below

[image]

[image]